# Analysis of reaction mixture by TLC and finding column chromatography condition

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, chromatography, purification

I am conducting an organic synthesis. Below is the TLC image.
[image: TLC image of reaction mixture]

I used dichloromethane:methanol:triethylamine=10:1:0.15 as eluent, but I stored it during 3 days, so it may be a little bit concentrated.

- Question 1. I used toluene to dissolve sample. If I spot only toluene and run TLC, and stain the plate, then there emerges brown color near the solvent front. I waited enough time to let toluene evaporate before staining, but are there chances that spot 1 is of toluene?
- Question 2. I am assuming that my desired product is basic, so I used triethylamine. When I fixed ratio of dichloromethane and methanol and changed only ratio of triethylamine, only the position of spot 7 changed and the others are unchanged. Then can I conclude that spot 7 is not part of spot 6 or tailing 2?

[image: TLC comparison for Et3N]

(sample is more concentrated than first image)

- Question 3. There are some tailings. Does existence of tailing always mean the band widening when I run the column chromatography? I heard that when I do the column, I had better use as minimum solvent as possible. But to prevent tailing, should I dilute the sample more? (I think the size of spot was small enough)
- Question 4. In UV, spot 6 looks like one big spot, but after staining it seems that middle is empty. Does this mean there are two or more other compounds in same position?
- Question 5. Is spot 4 and tailing 1 is same compound? Is spot 6 and tailing 2 is same compound? If I can't determine in this result, what should I do?

[image: another TLC image]

Another TLC image. Spot 4 is more identifiable. (sample is more concentrated than first image)

- Question 6. I assume that the longer distance spot moves, the more nonpolar it is. Even in very polar solvent system (i.e. dichloromethane:methanol=10:1) many spots are close to solvent front. To separate spot 1, 2, 3, and 4, how can I change the solvent system?

---

additional information

- starting material : aza-crown ether, bromothiophene, Pd catalyst, P ligand.
- expected product : N-substituted thiophene.
- aza-crown ether and spot 7 is not drawn up by solvent without (aza-crown ether is detectable only by ninhydrin) So I think I should use Et3N to separate these two.
- spot 3 is assumed to be Pd catalyst. bromothiophene and P ligand is not detectable by formaldehyde/H2SO4 staining.

Comment: Better you refer to some senior colleague at your place. I won't start any column using those conditions but what is the crude the material the amount the columns around etc it is crucial, togheter with possible major changes of the eluent. As for 1 answer should be no. #2 not really important #3a likely #3b no 4# likely but it might depend on the handling of the plate. #5&6 reduce polarity. Note that this is an attempt to help,only. Otherwise I would have answered. Also one should know if the reactants are there. The entire tlc is messy. Tailing is due to Et3N.

Comment: Finally the start line might have been to far from the eluent surface level. Togheter with a not well dried plate this means bigger spots. And to all: the capillaries for TLC should be extremely thin, not those called "for ematocrito".

Comment: @Alchimista Oh Is that start line too far? I line position at 1 cm from the bottom of the plate.

Comment: I have just guessed from the pics. And this would be important only if one doesn't dry the plate after deposition (and not existing with volatile eluents). But it is the last problem with your TLC

Comment: @Alchimista I used heat gun after developing. But is it okay to use heat gun if some compounds on TLC is volatile?

Comment: think about it. At least they won't be gases. The plate must be dry even after deposition. Otherwise the spot starts the process.

Comment: @Alchimista Okay. I would try and compare the results again.

Comment: Any aminothiophene derivative is not going to be very basic - similar to an aniline but will show up on UV. Any residual thiophene SM or be-brominated Sm will be at solvent front. My guess is spot 6 is product. I would run a gradiented column starting with DCM and going to 5% MeOH then strip with 10% MeOH and added Et3N.

Comment: You should have idea of which the product is. A synthesis does not come out of nothing. That is why you check it while is taking place. Most of the time you are not interested in the isolation of everything. Etc. Try to discuss also with a senior student and the friendly people around. If any.

Comment: @Alchimista Sorry, organic synthesis is not main job in my lab, so there are no senior to discuss about synthesis, actually I'm doing this nearly alone. (seniors mainly work for electronics) I major in chemical engineering, not chemistry, so there are no colleague to discuss, too.

Comment: @Alchimista I know that I don't have to isolate all the things, but all spots except one (spot 3) are not matched with starting materials so I was confused about what the product is.

Comment: @Waylander For some reason my bromothiophene starting material is not detected by UV. What do you think about question 4?

Comment: It could be co-eluting with the phosphine oxide from the ligand. Did you try the permanganate dip for visualisation?

Comment: @Waylander I have image with permanganate dip, it has a change near solvent front and middle of the plate, but it is not unclear that this middle position is exactly spot 6. I would try again. When I spotted only P ligand, after permanganate dip, it was near the solvent front.

Comment: The oxide of the P ligand will run lower than the ligand and have a good UV spot

Comment: @KrangLee I see. Welcome to the "materials for electronics and the like" science world ;)

Comment: By the sheer size of the «blob» on the top of the TLC it is possible that your analyte solution either is too concentrated, or that you put the capillary with the analyte solution too often on the TLC prior running the TLC.  So you can't say if the different colours by staining are just by different concentration of the analyte, or by different compounds (well, looks like the one eluted first does not absorb much UV).  But it is better to ran with two lanes simultaneously, starting material and reaction (mixture), or three (co-spot), to ease assignment of the spots.

Comment: (Ctd.)  See, e.g., https://chem.libretexts.org/Ancillary_Materials/Demos_Techniques_and_Experiments/General_Lab_Techniques/Thin_Layer_Chromatography or https://chemistryhall.com/thin-layer-chromatography/.  But what excellent school lets you hang running these experiments in the dark with so little chemical supervision?

Comment: @Buttonwood Thank you for answers, I would try more experiments..

Comment: @Buttonwood likely real research rather than schooling....